# Qual a diferença entre a chamada de funções com "::" e "."?

Tags: ruby, operadores

Em ruby é possível fazer uma chamada de algum método, seja de algum objeto, tanto usando `::` quanto usando `.`. Qual a diferença entre os mesmos?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não é qualquer método que pode chamar assim. Você usa este operador para para indicar que está usando um *namespace*, um nome de módulo ou classe, até chegar em um membro, mas como está acessando um membro de módulo ou classe só pode acessar membros que fazem parte do tipo, mas não do objeto, portanto métodos estáticos podem ser acessados, mas não de instância. Também pode usar para campos e constantes, desde que pertencentes ao tipo ou ao módulo.

Exemplo:

```
x = 0
module Teste
  x = 0
  ::x = 1
end

puts x #global, vale 1
puts Teste::x #do módulo vale 0
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Ruby/Scope.rb).

Note que se usar o operador sem um nome a linguagem considera que é o nome global.

É só a forma usada para resolução de nomes com um qualificador específico. Então não confunda com o `.` que é usado para resolução de um membro de um objeto.